# jquery chosen.js plugin multiselect does not update

Tags: multi-select, jquery-chosen

Tried running this on a multi select.

```
$('#field-participants').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

without any luck. Not sure what I might be missing. It does work on a non multi select.
The id is of the select element. The new option has been added via ajax.
Docs here say it should work http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Edit:

Adding more code. This code is called by the success handler of my ajax request.
The select does get updated but the chosen part is not refreshed

```
updateParticipants: function(data) {
    var $select = $('#field-participants');
    $select.append(
    $('<option></option>')
    .val(data.value)
    .html(data.name));
    $select.trigger('liszt:updated');


}
```

Comment: Updated code to make it clearer. Tried running it directly in Firebug too.

Answer (score 0):

They way you handle the `liszt:updated` is correct.  But there seems to be a small mistake, not sure whether I am correct.

Try the below code.

```
updateParticipants: function(data) {        
    $('#field-participants').append('<option value="' + data.value + '">'+ data.name + '</option>');
    $('#field-participants').trigger('liszt:updated');
}
```

Hope this is clear.